# Сохранить с TextBox в ComboBox

Tags: c#, textbox, combobox, postgresql9.5

[Form1 http://i12.pixs.ru/storage/0/5/2/form1jpg_4473358_24731052.jpg](http://i12.pixs.ru/storage/0/5/2/form1jpg_4473358_24731052.jpg)
[Form1 http://i12.pixs.ru/storage/0/7/1/form2jpg_1765146_24731071.jpg](http://i12.pixs.ru/storage/0/7/1/form2jpg_1765146_24731071.jpg)

Как из 2й формы значения введеные в TexBox'ы сохранить с именем Name(TextBox) в ComboBox. И как при выборе из ComboBox эти значения перенести в connectionString?

```
class Connection
    {
        private string connectionString;
        protected NpgsqlCommand command;
        protected NpgsqlConnection connection;
        protected NpgsqlDataReader reader;


        public PostgreConnection()
        {
            connectionString = @"Server ="+ ServerBox.Text +
                                ";Port="+ PortBox.Text +
                                ";Database="+ DatabaseBox.Text +
                                ";User ID=" + UserIDBox.Text +
                                ";Password=" + PasswordBox.Text;

            connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Проще всего создать класс (или структуру) со следующими свойствами:`Server`,`Port`,`Database`,`ID`,`Password`. В вашей диалоговой форме объявить объект этого класса и при нажатии `Save` заносить туда информацию. Из первой формы просто извлекаете это свойство и проверяете на `null`.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper А можете оформить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov спасибо, что напомнили. Не всегда есть возможность написать полноценный ответ :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тех случаях когда вам нужно вернуть из второй (диалоговой) формы какую-то информацию проще всего начать с создания вспомогательного класс (или структуры). Он должен полностью описывать те данные которые вы хотите использовать в первой форме.

Конкретно в вашем случае класс может быть примерно таким:

```
public class ConnectionData
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format
            ("Server = {0};Port={1};Database={2};User ID={3};Password={4}",
                Server, Port, Database, ID, Password);
    }

}
```

Насчет второй части вопроса. Вы можете хранить все ваши строки для подключения в списке (подробнее о `BindingList` [в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
BindingList<ConnectionData> list = new BindingList<ConnectionData>();
```

дальше в конструкторе устанавливаете его в качестве источника данных для вашего `ComboBox`:

```
//тут заполнение списка предварительными данными
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
```

и каждый при добавлении новых данных они будут автоматически отображаться в вашем выпадающем списке. Конкретное отображение данных в `ComboBox` по умолчанию зависит от того как вы переопределите метода `ToString` в вашем классе.

Теперь непосредственно об передачи данных со второй формы.

В диалоговой форме добавляете свойство:

```
public ConnectionData Connection_data { get; set; }
```

и при обработке клика по кнопке `Save` заполняете его информацией.
В первой форме вам останется только сравнить `Connection_data` с `null`:

```
//...
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
if (form2.Connection_data != null)
    list.Add(form2.Connection_data);
```

---

В новой версии C# (6.0) вы можете использовать нуль-условный оператор и интерполяцию строк. Подробнее о том, что было добавлено можно прочесть, например, [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249555/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!